# Pandas error TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have inherited this piece of code

```
dummy_data1 = {
    'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
    'Feature2': ['Mouse', 'dog', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN],
    'dates': ['12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'dates'])

df1 = df1.assign(
                    Feature2=lambda df: df.Feature2.where(
                        ~df.Feature2.str.isnumeric(),
                        pd.to_numeric(df.Feature2, errors="coerce").astype("Int64"),
                    )
    )
    
print(df1)
```

I know that this is because of the np.NAN value. What does the code do? My understanding is that it tries to convert the String to Int, if it is of type integer. Also please tell me how to overcome this issue.

Comment: fill those NaN's with `fillna()` to either True or False according to your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try via `pd.to_numeric()` and then fill NaN's:

```
df['Feature2']=pd.to_numeric(df['Feature2'], errors="coerce").fillna(df['Feature2'])
```

OR

go with the `where()` condition by filling those NaN's with `fillna()` in your condition `~df.Feature2.str.isnumeric()`:

```
df['Feature2']=df['Feature2'].where(~df.Feature2.str.isnumeric().fillna(True),
                     pd.to_numeric(df.Feature2, errors="coerce").astype("Int64")
                    )
```